# Does GAE Search API do spell checks

Tags: google-app-engine, google-search-api

I'm talking about this API:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/

Does it allow spell checks?  For example: if I create an index of documents, and in those documents I have words like "iphone", "android", etc.  If I search for "iphoen" instead can it still return the correct results?

Answer (score 1):

No, it cannot. It is just an index - what you put it, you get back.

You need to implement your own logic for spelling errors. If a user searches for "iphoen", you either return all results for "iphoen" and suggest "iphone" query instead, or, if you are very confident that a search term was mis-spelled, do a search for "iphone" right away and ask a user if a "iphoen" should be used. This is how Google search works. This is, obviously, not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not do this. It does direct text matching. Taken from the link you provided:

> The simplest query, sometimes called a "global search" is a string that contains only field values. This search uses a string that searches for documents that contain the words "rose" and "water":

```
index.search("rose water");
```

Based on this, it's implied reasonably well that it will not do fuzzy matches for you. However, you could write an extension class that takes a string and tests variants against the Search API. You could then return any successful queries and report the fuzzy match. In this way, your class would take `"ipohne"` and eventually try `"iphone"` and return a successful query.